# How to build an Array with Bison/Yacc and a Recursive Rule

Tags: c, yacc, bison

With Bison, I figured out how to get everything into one long string as follows:

```
arg_list:
    WORD arg_list { strcat( $1, "IFS" ); $$ = strcat($1, $2); }  |
    WORD
    ;
```

and:

```
WORD arg_list { printf("%s, %s\n", $1, $2); }
```

But the problem is that I will then have to split up $2 in the second rule again to parse it.  Is there a way to populate an array instead of just using concatenation?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

If I need to build something like a linked list that could make sense, just not sure what would be the proper way to bind to arg_list, and then clean up the memory.

Comment: You should build lists left-recursively with LR parsers like Bison, niot right-recursively. Otherwise the production stack needs to contain every element of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an array type with a push_front operation, this is trivially:

```
arg_list:
    WORD arg_list { $$ = $2.push_front($1); }
    WORD { $$ = new Array<string>($1); }
```

without that, it requires more work.  You can use a vector and add the strings on the end (which will be in the reversed order).  Or you can use a linked list (which is easier if you're using straight C):

```
arg_list:
    WORD arg_list { $$ = malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem));
                    $$->next = $2;
                    $$->val = $1; }
    WORD          { $$ = malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem));
                    $$->next = 0;
                    $$->val = $1; }
```

Comment: This is all straight C, the second one mostly makes sense, but I haven't gotten to the part where $$ has members, know what I might google exactly to find that?

Comment: $$ is just a variable of the type declared in the %type declaration of this rule, or of YYSTYPE if there is no %type declaration.  Commonly, that will be a 'struct list *' for arg_list, so '$$->next' and '$$->val' will be elements of the pointed-to list object.  In the C++ case its much more complex, depending on how you've defined things with potential references and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

```
%union {
  char *char_ptr;
}
%token STRING
%type <char_ptr> STRING string
%%
...
string:
    STRING        /* Lexic analyzer return STRING and set yylval = yytext; */
  | string STRING
    { char *str = (char*) malloc(strlen($1) + strlen($2) + 1);
      strcpy(str, $1);
      strcat(str, $2);
      free($2);
      free($1);
      $$ = str;
    }
  ;
%%
```