# Building a linked list in yacc with left recursive Grammar

Tags: yacc

I want to build a linked list of data in `yacc`. 
**My Grammar reads like this:**

```
list: item
  | list ',' item
  ;
```

I have put the appropriate structures in place in the declarations section. But I am not able to figure out a way to get a linked list out of this data. I have to store the recursively obtained data and then redirect it for other purposes.

Basically I am looking for a solution like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429820/5134525
But this solution is for right recursion and doesn't work with left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends heavily on how you implement your linked list, but once you have that, it is straight-forward.  Something like:

```
struct list_node {
    struct list_node  *next;
    value_t           value;
};
struct list {
    struct list_node  *head, **tail;
};

struct list *new_list() {
    struct list *rv = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    rv->head = 0;
    rv->tail = &rv->head;
    return rv; }
void push_back(struct list *list, value_t value) {
    struct list_node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    node->next = 0;
    node->value = value;
    *list->tail = node;
    list->tail = &node->next; }
```

allows you to write your yacc code as:

```
list: item { push_back($$ = new_list(), $1); }
    | list ',' item { push_back($$ = $1, $3); }
    ;
```

of course, you should probably add checks for running out of memory, and exit gracefully in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a left recursive rule, then you need to push the new item at the end of the list rather than the beginning.

If your linked list implementation doesn't support `push_back`, then push the successive items at the front and reverse the list when its finished.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
list
    : item
    {
        $$ = new MyList<SomeType>();
        $$.add($1);
    }
    | list ',' item
    {
        $1.add($3);
        $$ = $1;
    }
    ;
```

assuming you are using C++, which you didn't state, and assuming you have some `MyList<T>` class with an `add(T)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I forgot to mention the language I am using. I am actually using C

Comment: If you're using C++, change `MyList` to `std::list` and `add` to `push_back`  -- it's silly to define your own when the standard library does it for you

Comment: @Sharad: C doesn't have any standard linked-list type, so your first step is to define that.